# Creating new rows in dataset based on conditions

Tags: r

So I have data with three columns. You will notice Cincinnati has 10 rows, while Clemson has 8 rows.

**Data**

```
structure(list(player_id = c(473L, 653L, 816L, 885L, 906L, 969L, 
998L, 102L, 106L, 107L, 23L, 33L, 44L, 67L, 74L, 80L, 87L, 91L
), rating = c(0.8756, 0.8646, 0.8572, 0.8547, 0.8539, 0.8519, 
0.8506, 0.8498, 0.8477, 0.8477, 0.9867, 0.9822, 0.9764, 0.9673, 
0.9654, 0.9644, 0.9614, 0.9566), school = c("Cincinnati", "Cincinnati", 
"Cincinnati", "Cincinnati", "Cincinnati", "Cincinnati", "Cincinnati", 
"Cincinnati", "Cincinnati", "Cincinnati", "Clemson", "Clemson", 
"Clemson", "Clemson", "Clemson", "Clemson", "Clemson", "Clemson"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))

player_id   rating  school
473 0.8756  Cincinnati
653 0.8646  Cincinnati
816 0.8572  Cincinnati
885 0.8547  Cincinnati
906 0.8539  Cincinnati
969 0.8519  Cincinnati
998 0.8506  Cincinnati
102 0.8498  Cincinnati
106 0.8477  Cincinnati
107 0.8477  Cincinnati
23  0.9867  Clemson
33  0.9822  Clemson
44  0.9764  Clemson
67  0.9673  Clemson
74  0.9654  Clemson
80  0.9644  Clemson
87  0.9614  Clemson
91  0.9566  Clemson
```

The goal is, I'm trying to get any school who doesn't have 10 rows to 10 rows by creating a "Placeholder" row of sorts that is based off the current average of the rating field. So for Clemson, that would include two "Placeholder" rows with a rating of 0.9701. So the final output would look something like this:

```
player_id   rating  school
473 0.8756  Cincinnati
653 0.8646  Cincinnati
816 0.8572  Cincinnati
885 0.8547  Cincinnati
906 0.8539  Cincinnati
969 0.8519  Cincinnati
998 0.8506  Cincinnati
102 0.8498  Cincinnati
106 0.8477  Cincinnati
107 0.8477  Cincinnati
23  0.9867  Clemson
33  0.9822  Clemson
44  0.9764  Clemson
67  0.9673  Clemson
74  0.9654  Clemson
80  0.9644  Clemson
87  0.9614  Clemson
91  0.9566  Clemson
0   0.9701  Clemson
0   0.9701  Clemson
```

What would be the most effective way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could expand the dataset with `complete` on the basis of a `row_number` column after grouping by 'school', then `replace` the `NA`  element with the `mean` of the 'rating'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
n <- 10
df1 %>%
     group_by(school) %>% 
     mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
     ungroup %>% 
     complete(school, rn = unique(rn), fill = list(player_id = 0)) %>%     
     # // if all groups should be having fixed number of rows
     # complete(school, rn = seq_len(n), fill = list(player_id = 0))
     group_by(school) %>% 
     mutate(rating = replace_na(rating, mean(rating, na.rm = TRUE)))    
# A tibble: 20 x 4
# Groups:   school [2]
#   school        rn player_id rating
#   <chr>      <int>     <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 Cincinnati     1       473  0.876
# 2 Cincinnati     2       653  0.865
#3 Cincinnati      3       816  0.857
# 4 Cincinnati     4       885  0.855
# 5 Cincinnati     5       906  0.854
# 6 Cincinnati     6       969  0.852
# 7 Cincinnati     7       998  0.851
# 8 Cincinnati     8       102  0.850
# 9 Cincinnati     9       106  0.848
#10 Cincinnati    10       107  0.848
#11 Clemson        1        23  0.987
#12 Clemson        2        33  0.982
#13 Clemson        3        44  0.976
#14 Clemson        4        67  0.967
#15 Clemson        5        74  0.965
#16 Clemson        6        80  0.964
#17 Clemson        7        87  0.961
#18 Clemson        8        91  0.957
#19 Clemson        9         0  0.970
#20 Clemson       10         0  0.970
```

---

With the OP's new dataset

```
n <- 20
out <- df1 %>%
         group_by(school) %>% 
         filter(n() < n) %>% 
         mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
         ungroup %>% 
         complete(school, rn = seq_len(n), fill = list(rank= 0)) %>%
         group_by(school) %>% 
         mutate(rating = replace_na(rating, mean(rating, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
         bind_rows(df1 %>% 
                      group_by(school) %>% 
                      filter(n() >=n)) 

range(table(out$school))
#[1] 20 57
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
setDT(df1)[,  .SD[seq_len(max(c(n, .N)))], school
     ][, rating := fifelse(is.na(rating), mean(rating, na.rm = TRUE), rating),
       school][, lapply(.SD, na.locf0)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(player_id = c(473L, 653L, 816L, 885L, 906L, 969L, 
998L, 102L, 106L, 107L, 23L, 33L, 44L, 67L, 74L, 80L, 87L, 91L
), rating = c(0.8756, 0.8646, 0.8572, 0.8547, 0.8539, 0.8519, 
0.8506, 0.8498, 0.8477, 0.8477, 0.9867, 0.9822, 0.9764, 0.9673, 
0.9654, 0.9644, 0.9614, 0.9566), school = c("Cincinnati", "Cincinnati", 
"Cincinnati", "Cincinnati", "Cincinnati", "Cincinnati", "Cincinnati", 
"Cincinnati", "Cincinnati", "Cincinnati", "Clemson", "Clemson", 
"Clemson", "Clemson", "Clemson", "Clemson", "Clemson", "Clemson"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219646/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-creating-new-rows-in-dataset-based-on-conditions).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R way, with the `split/apply/combine` strategy, see [Hadley's JSS article](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/plyr.pdf).

```
res <- lapply(split(df1, df1$school), function(X){
  if(nrow(X) < 10){
    tmp <- data.frame(player_id = rep(0, 10 - nrow(X)), 
                      rating = mean(X[['rating']]),
                      school = X[1, 'school'])
    rbind(X, tmp)
  } else X
})
res <- do.call(rbind, res)
row.names(res) <- NULL

res
#   player_id  rating     school
#1        473 0.87560 Cincinnati
#2        653 0.86460 Cincinnati
#3        816 0.85720 Cincinnati
#4        885 0.85470 Cincinnati
#5        906 0.85390 Cincinnati
#6        969 0.85190 Cincinnati
#7        998 0.85060 Cincinnati
#8        102 0.84980 Cincinnati
#9        106 0.84770 Cincinnati
#10       107 0.84770 Cincinnati
#11        23 0.98670    Clemson
#12        33 0.98220    Clemson
#13        44 0.97640    Clemson
#14        67 0.96730    Clemson
#15        74 0.96540    Clemson
#16        80 0.96440    Clemson
#17        87 0.96140    Clemson
#18        91 0.95660    Clemson
#19         0 0.97005    Clemson
#20         0 0.97005    Clemson
```